# Team Foundation Server - Unauthorized intermittently

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Recently I've had this error pop up intermittently when trying to do things in a project:

1. Checking In Changes
2. Making edits to a recently unchanged file (checking out a file I assume)
3. Opening Source Control Explorer

[image]

After a couple of tries or reloads it end up working. But, it's really annoying and just started happening.

1. I tried clearing Internet Explorer browser history.
2. I tried changing the login type microsoft.com/devicelogin.
3. I tried clearing Visual Studio cache. (not sure if i cleared everything)

Side Note: I changed the name of my laptop recently and that seems to be around the same time I started having issues, not sure if that is related.

The same thing happens when using Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 community versions.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!